# Unable Internet Connection in android emulator my new app, accounts & sync and other apps

Tags: android

Internet is working in only android emulator's browser.  But not work in remains all application like my new app, accounts & sync.  So, I have not idea that why internet is working in browser and not working in my new app, accounts & sync.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u have this in ur manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I have mention that internet is not working in all app and also in accounts & sync.  accounts & sync is not made by me.  It is google app.....

Comment: from where do you run the emulator

Comment: I have try both though command Prompt and also though eclipse.

Comment: it also from both though command Prompt and also though eclipse

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35901/discussion-between-kels-and-prakhar)